# Wordpress menu permalink redirects to wrong page

Tags: menus, permalinks, pages

I have created a new pricing page that contains a new pricing table.

I renamed the old page `Pricing` to `Pricing-old`. Also deleted the permalink and hit OK so that the new permalink is set to `/pricing-old`.

I renamed the new page `Pricing-test` to `Pricing`. I deleted the permalink and hit OK so that the new permalink is set to `/pricing`.

In `Appearance-->Menus`, I completely removed the old menu item `Pricing` and saved. I then left and went back there, saw that there is now a `Pricing` and a `Pricing-old`. I added `Pricing`.

I saved everything.

For some crazy, crazy reason, the menu item `Pricing` which has the permalink `/pricing`, when you click on it, takes you to the `pricing-old` page!!! This is not at all intuitive. What do I do?

***UPDATE***
What a MESS! I decided to just change the reference to the pricing table inside the old page instead of expect WP to do what it is supposed to do. I reversed the steps above. The result is continuous redirects resulting in an error page, and a site that no longer accepts new customers.

Comment: Try deleting any trashed pages that could be relevant to the issue, regenerate permalinks, and if the site uses a caching plugin, clear the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regenerate your permalinks. Resetting permalinks rebuilds your link structure for WordPress. Often, this process must be performed after migrating a WordPress website, or when troubleshooting 404 errrors. This is accompished by choosing a different permalinks setting, and saving it. Then putting the permalink setting back to the original setting and saving it again. This is a common step when Troubleshooting WordPress problems.

Comment: Thanks very much. The Yoast Premium plugin was causing all of the redirects. Once those were deleted and the pemalinks regenerated, everything worked.